I'm going to synthesize several sinewaves to make musical instruments such as violins and pianos. What frequency do you need to make each instrument?
I'm going to synthesize several sine waves to make musical instruments such as violins and pianos. What frequency do you need to make each instrument?

This question is similar to: Why doesn't my synthesized note sound natural?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The nature of this question suggests you need to learn a lot of the fundamentals of musical sounds first.  As asked, your 24-word question would be answered by volumes of knowledge gained over a century of study and experimentation.  Explain what you've learned so far and try to focus your question on one detailed point.

Well, many frequencies. Violins can play many “notes,” that is, (fundamental) frequencies, including notes “between” the named ones on a piano. And the piano’s range extends way lower than the violin’s. And if you’re doing additive synthesis, you’ll need a lot more than the fundamental.

Closely related question (on Signal Processing): Mathematical equation for the sound wave that a piano makes

The Fourier transform does what you want, but is not practical for a homebrew approach. You won't get sufficiently precise input curves and the results will disappoint you.
Apart from that the sound varies significantly over time and the beginning phase (called attack) is especially important for getting a characteristic impression.
Try any DAW program, select the instrument of your choice to get an idea of the achievable similarity by any means of synthesis.

Note that some of r these daw instruments are based on samples. Not that it always make them more realistic ;)

Ooops! That is a tall question.
First: the base notes. In western music we most often use equal temperament. Take one note, say the middle A=440Hz. The A one octave above is 880Hz, the A one octave belowe is 220Hz. The scale has 11 notes inside an octave, so you need all of those to be able to play any tune. The difference between any two half-notes is the 12 square root of 2 (look it up).
Secondly: instrument sounds are partly known by their overtone spectrum. Overtones are generally 2 times, 3 times, 4 times and so on times the base note. So for an A at 440Hz you will have an overtone mix of 880, 1320, 1760 and so on. The exact mix will differ between different instruments. Some instruments have mostly odd overtones, some mostly even, some close to none. If you have access to a Hammond type organ with drawbars you can try this mix (available in many DAW type programs).
Thirdly: identifying differing instruments is very much dependant on the start of notes. This will include various envelopes (starting fast, slow and so on) and might include wind noises or percussive elements. These will necessitate a library of various sounds, not necessarily at any specific frequency.
Good luck.
